# Conjugacy Classes of $A_n$

Tags: group-theory

Am I right that conjugacy classes of group $A_n$ can be obtained from conjugacy classes of $S_n$ (which are in correspondence with Young diagrams). If class $$C(h)=\{\sigma h {\sigma}^{-1}|\sigma\in S_n\}$$
contains independent cycles of only odd length and length of all cycles are different then $C(h)$ in $A_n$ split to two classes
$$C_1(h)=\{\sigma h {\sigma}^{-1}|\sigma\in A_n\}$$
$$C_2(h)=\{\sigma \tau h {\tau}^{-1} {\sigma}^{-1}|\sigma\in A_n\}.$$
I only interested in the answer.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: answer is yes..

Comment: [This gives you the answer, and it is yes.](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Splitting_criterion_for_conjugacy_classes_in_the_alternating_group)